# Pyspark - Convert specific string to date format

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a date pyspark dataframe with a string column in the format of `Mon-YY` eg. 'Jan-17' and I am attempting to convert this into a date column.
I've tried to do it like this but it does not work out :

```
df.select(to_timestamp(df.t, 'MON-YY HH:mm:ss').alias('dt'))
```

Is it possible to do it like in SQL or do I need to write a special function for conversion ?

Comment: try `df.select(to_timestamp('t',"MMM-yy").alias("dt"))`

Answer (score 0):

You should use valid [Java date format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html). The following will work

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
df.select(psf.to_timestamp(psf.col('t'), 'MMM-YY HH:mm:ss').alias('dt'))
```

`Jan-17` will become `2017-01-01` in that case

## Example

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([("Jan-17 00:00:00",'a'),("Apr-19 00:00:00",'b')], ['t','x'])
df.show(2)
+---------------+---+
|              t|  x|
+---------------+---+
|Jan-17 00:00:00|  a|
|Apr-19 00:00:00|  b|
+---------------+---+
```

Conversion to timestamp:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
df.select(psf.to_timestamp(psf.col('t'), 'MMM-YY HH:mm:ss').alias('dt')).show(2)
+-------------------+
|                 dt|
+-------------------+
|2017-01-01 00:00:00|
|2018-12-30 00:00:00|
+-------------------+
```